# Implementing Facebook login using OpenID

Tags: authentication, facebook, openid, openid-provider

Is there an OpenID endpoint that authenticates a Facebook user using OpenID? I have an implementation of an OpenID consumer that uses OpenID login, and I don't care to add yet another login scheme, nor replace it with rpxnow (which would mean transfer of all user identifiers to a third party -- and with a free, ad unsupported service, which won't be able to pay for any subscription fees third party service provider might introduce, that is not something I care to do).

So, is there an OpenID provider for Facebook?

---

I am looking for a possibly third party provider or an open self-hosted solution. If none exists, I'll implement OAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Facebook doesn't support OpenID. Use [Facebook OAuth authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I found as well, but supporting only OpenID would still be the best way to go for me. I'll see if someone else has a better solution.

Comment: Accepting since there seems to be no better answer. I do have some issues with getting OAuth to work (tested with Google, though); hopefully I'll resolve them.